# ASP.NET Bundling - Ignoring second JS file

Tags: asp.net, bundling-and-minification

I have set up a simple test using ASP.NET's bundling and minification feature. I have two very simple js files:

*~/JS/Site.js*

```
(function echo1() {
    alert("this is site.js");
})();
```

*~/JS/test.js*

```
(function echo2(value) {
    alert("and this is test.js");
})();
```

I've created a bundle as follows:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/scripts/site-globals").Include(
    "~/JS/Site.js", 
    "~/JS/test.js"));
```

and referenced the bundle on the page using `@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/scripts/site-globals")`

---

When I run the site under debug (`<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />` in web.config) I get the expected result - two alert boxes show one after the other.

However, when I run change to release (`<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5" />`) - **I only see the first alert box, and the combined JS file that gets sent to the browser has completely ignored the content of test.js.**

The "combined and minified" output is as below, and wrongly only includes the code from Site.js:

```
(function(){alert("this is site.js")})()
```

Any ideas on why this is happening would be much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Try renaming the second js file, there is some special handling for certain filenames and I wonder if "test" has a special meaning.  Just a guess.  Double check that casing on the name matches, although *usually* on a windows platform that doesn't matter.

Comment: @AaronLS - thanks for your suggestions - I have tried using "firstthing.js" and "secondthing.js" and checked the case but it still doesn't work unfortunately. I think there must be something dodgy with my solution because I can't replicate this in an empty project. Even removing all other scripts/css/bundles doesn't seem to change anything though :S

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found out what was causing this problem. If any of the javascript files have a comment as the last line, they will be **combined together without a newline**, causing the first line of the next file to be commented out.

Here's a link to another question on stack overflow which demonstrates this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14223945/1145963[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14223945/1145963)

In my case, I was using the **Web Essentials Visual Studio plugin** to minify my javascript files. It was creating a .js.map file for each JS file, and at the end of each .min.js file was a commented line like this, which turned out to be causing the problem:

```
//@ sourceMappingURL=somefile.min.js.map
```

Since I didn't need the mapping files, I turned this feature off using `Options -> Web Essentials -> Javascript -> Set Generate source maps (.map) to false`

Hope this helps anyone who finds this problem!

Answer (score 1):

Matt, your bundling code looks correct, do you receive any js errors in the browser console when running in Release mode?  Also as a side note, are you aware that you can simply define the folder path to your JS files and they will all be included?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. There are no js errors - it just seems to be ignoring the content of the second file in the bundled output. Frustratingly I can only seem to replicate the problem in this particular solution and I can't seem to reproduce it in an empty project! I did know that you can define a folder path, but I presume you would then lose control over the order of the bundled files (I don't want to have the hassle of renaming my files with numeric prefixes etc)?