# ASP.NET bundle does not work when deployed (debug="false")

Tags: javascript, asp.net

In development bundling works as expected with uncombined and unminified files but after deploying a site with web.config set enable the bundles

```
<compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.5" />
```

the result of get a request to a bundle may include a comment at the top similar to the following

```
/* Minification failed. Returning unminified contents.
.. errors like JS1002 or JSxxxx errors
```

In other cases no errors are thrown from minification but some javascripts fails to run or errors during execution.

What syntax in otherwise working javascript might cause this behavior after bundling?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One situation that can cause this is a single line comment // as the last line of a javascript file.  This will cause the next file appened to have at least the first line also commented out

if forexample you have a bundle

```
bundles.Add(New ScriptBundle("~/bundles/test").Include(
            "~/Scripts/adder.js",
            "~/Scripts/printer.js"))
```

adder.js

```
function adder(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
//this is the adder.js
```

printer.js

```
printer = true;

if (printer) {
    alert("It works");
    document.getElementById("itWorked").textContent = "It worked";    
}
```

Comment: Are you answering your own question in that this solved your problem?

Comment: Yes, this was the situation I ran into hoping this may help someone in the future.

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution and including a clear example. I found that the javascript minification feature of Web Essentials caused this (by including a commented line at the end of the minified javascript as you mentioned here). I linked to your answer in my similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15160552/1145963 - might be of use to anyone using Web Essentials.